# Excel Solver Limit Issue

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have Solver running through VBA and it has a variable number of items it will have to process every time.  The problem I am having is once the list to process goes over 20 it will not attempt to any of the entries over 20.  Anything under 20 it works perfect.

I have a loop built in that takes the results and pastes them into another location and that updates the Order_Rem total and the VBA runs Solver until that number is zero.

If I have more than 20 items to process it ignores everything over 20 and once it gets towards the end it will continue to output items that are already processed down to zero infinitely.

So am I missing something or doing something wrong causing it to ignore everything above 20?

Hopefully this makes sense, let me know if I need to clarify.

*Layout*
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/336h5.png)

*Solver*
[Solver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waHZp.png)

[List Limit Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuV04.jpg)

[Failed Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6rd2.png)

```vb
Do Until Range("ORDER_REM") = 0
    
    'Range("CONTROL_TEST").Value = 1
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=Range("MAXPOUNDS"), MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:=Range("CONTROL_TEST") _
    , Engine:=3
                 
    'The control test must be an integer value
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("CONTROL_TEST"), Relation:=4
    
    Range("CONTROL_TEST").Value = 1
    
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("CONTROL_TEST"), _
        Relation:=1, FormulaText:=ws1.Range("control_max")
    
    'The control test must be >= 1
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("CONTROL_TEST"), _
        Relation:=3, FormulaText:=ws1.Range("control_min")
    
    'The remaining space must be >= zero
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$AB$2:$AB$12"), _
        Relation:=3, FormulaText:=ws1.Range("min_oven_space")
    
    'the order remaining must be >= zero
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$AD$2:$AD$12"), _
        Relation:=3, FormulaText:=ws1.Range("min_oven_space")

    SolverSolve True

    Range("RESULTS").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AI3").Offset(offsetRow, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _ 
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
    offsetRow = offsetRow + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Contact Frontline - they have a Solver with larger parameters.

Comment: Standard Solver limit is 200 "Decision variables" and 100 constraints  - https://www.solver.com/standard-excel-solver-dealing-problem-size-limits#:~:text=Analytic%20Solver%20products.-,Limits%20on%20Decision%20Variables,both%20linear%20and%20nonlinear%20problems.

Comment: What range does `Range("ORDER_REM")` refer to?

Comment: The "ORDER_REM" is sum of items left to process.  Basically we have 20 (more/ or less) items with a varying amount quantity under them.  As the Solver processes that "ORDER_REM" decreases until zero.

Comment: I don't think I am hitting the 200 decision variable limit, am I?  I have a table built with formulas to calculation the MAXPOUNDS.  Solver should just be cycling through 20-30 options to get the MAXPOUNDS.

Comment: If it just keeps on running then seems like `Range("ORDER_REM") = 0` is never True?  Otherwise with all the formulas etc it's a bit difficult to tell what else might be going on.

Comment: ...note that an empty cell with be equal to zero as well as one which has an explicit 0 entered.

Comment: That is correct, it continues to run because none of the items over 20 are ever process therefore "ORDER_REM" never gets down to 0.